# Правильная синхронизация MultiValueMap

Tags: многопоточность, java, синхронизация

Опишу приложение полностью.

Есть группа потоков - *обработчики* json. они берут json-объекты из SynchronousQueue, которая называется jsonQueue и обрабатывают. Есть группа потоков - *генераторы* json-объектов, которая генерирует json и ложит в jsonQueue.
Чтобы сгенерировать json генераторы нужны данные, которые загружаются пулом-загрузчиком.В пул-загрузчик сабмитится таск(Runnable) который говорит - загрузи мне столько-то данных для такого-то id . Json объект состоит из поля id и поля value. Одному id может соответствовать много value, но сам json-объект содержит только 1 id и 1 value.

*Обработчики* работают так: while(true) {берем из jsonQueue объект и обрабатываем}

*Генераторы* работают так :while(true) {генерируем json объект и пихаем в jsonQueue}

То есть за 1 итерацию поток-генератор генерирует 1 объект в котором есть 1 id и 1 value и пихает в jsonQueue.

Для того чтобы каждый раз, когда поток-генератор пытается сгенерировать объект не нужно было для данного id загружать с БД value, я до старта группы-генераторов загружаю для каждого id *несколько* value => *собственно для этого и использую МультиМэп*. МультиМэп у меня представляет собой Мэп, где ключи - id , value - коллекция value которая соответсвует id.
После первоначальной загрузки данных, я запускаю потоки-генераторы.
Они работают следующим образом: случайно выбирают из набора ключей ключ, по этому ключу получают коллекцию values, ,берут *1* value и генерируют json, который теперь состоит из id и выбранного value. После чего выбранный value удаляется из коллекции соответствующей нашему id. Если поток-генератор обнаруживает что для id коллекция пуста - то он сабмитит таск в пул-загрузчик - *загрузи мне ещё value для данного id*

Вот, скажем такая полная картина

Comment: Всё дело в том, что сама идея бредова на корню. Применять MultiValueMap вместе с LinkedBlockgingQueue - это абсурд.

Comment: Почему Вы так считаете ?

Comment: Потому что вы и MultiValueMap используете не по назначению, и LinkedBlockingQueue. Почитайте, для чего они вообще нужны.

Comment: A MultiValueMap decorates another map, allowing it to have more than one value for a key-так я его и использую,по ключу привязываю коллекцию с многими значениями.Так уж вышло что по логике работы в качестве value мне нужна функцинальность очереди а не,скажем,Листа.Сделано это для удобства сабмита таска на обновление,мне показалоссь что вытащить элемент из очереди и в случае если он null засабмитить таск для обновления очереди для этого ключа удобней,чем каждый раз проверять size Листа и если он =0 сабмитить такой же таск.Ну как Вы,с точки зрения опыта,посоветуете реализовать такую логику?.

Comment: Вы лучше задачку поподробнее опишите, а не свои структуры данных и потоки (под *таск* Вы понимаете поток (thread)?)

Comment: Под *таск* понимаю Runnable который сабмитится в пул, кстати в пуле 1 поток(говорю так на всякий случай, хотя это не суть важно)
Что касается задачи, то вроде как я описал все что требуется =) Подробней вроде никак уже нельзя
Проапдейтил Вопрос.

Comment: Было бы неплохо услышать задачу, которую вы пытались таким способом решить.

Comment: Если MAP не меняется (в описанной части), то синхронизация не нужна.
Поток, выбирающий **value** из очереди просто должен корректно обрабатывать ситуацию *очередь пуста*.

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue уже и так потокобезопасна. Но её основная фишка - это операция take().

Comment: Ну так в том был и вопрос,как в таком случае использовать readWriteLock. вместо LinkedBlockingQueue я могу использовать и ArrayBlockingQueue, это не кретично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае, вам надо посмотреть в сторону [ExecutorCompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). С его помощью запускаете вычисление частей, соответстсующих одному id. И ожидаете завершения всех частей. После того, как это произойдёт, запускаете тастку на обработку всех результатов, связанных с этим id.

Comment: в том то и суть что у меня нет таска для одновременной обработки *всех* результатов. у меня таск который берет *один из* результатов, берет соответствующий id, генерирует json объект и пихает его в очередь этих объектов, после чего опять берет *один из* результатов и проделывает то же самое, если результатов нет -> сабмит таск на загрузку новых результатов для этого id

Comment: А кто же с кем параллельно работает ?

Comment: Мап используется 
1. группой потоков-генераторов - которая тащит из неё id, value из коллекции, удаляет этот value из коллекции, формирует json пихает в очередь jsonов. и начинает тот же самый процесс заново. Если Коллекция для value - пуста, сабмитится таск на обновление в пул(кот. содержит 1 поток), после чего пробуется сгенерировать json для другого id(у которого есть элементы в collection)
2. пул который обновляет очереди для указанного id

Comment: Группа генераторов (как мы в процессе вопросов-ответов выяснили) не требует синхронизации. Поток, обновляющий очереди работает синхронно с этой группой (либо он либо группа). Собственно остается только момент переключения между группой и потоком обновителем. 

Вы используете wait/notify и какой-нибудь счетчик ? Это место видимо надо синхронизировать для потоков группы генераторов. 

Так ?

Comment: Честно говоря, мне всё равно не понятно, кто чего берёт и куда девает и зачем там коллекция сооотвествует id, если уже есть queue. И не понятно, зачем вообще нужна мапа. Почему таска не может загрузить часть данных для id, а потом её обработать, не складывая в мапу.

Comment: Группа генераторов не требует синхронизации. Поток, обновляющий очереди работает синхронно с этой группой (либо он либо группа)>> Можно тут подробней, почему не требует ? из-за блокирующей очереди? но ведь она это value для мапа, который не потокобезопасен. Ведь пока обновляющий поток обновляет очередь(тем самым,в моем понимании,изменяет структуру мапа), другие потоки-генераторы из мапа читают. То есть если б у меня вместо МультиМапа был бы обычный Мап то тут никак нельзя было бы без readWriteLock - это как я представляю, поправьте,пожалуйста, если не прав

Comment: "пока обновляющий поток обновляет очередь(тем самым,в моем понимании,изменяет структуру мапа)" - с какой стати? Изменение value не влияет никак на внутреннее состояние мапы.

Comment: Мой лимит комментариев заканчивается.

Хотя я не правильно понял, что в какой последовательности у Вас работает, на ответ о синхронизации это не влияет.
Обновление очереди **не меняет структуру мапа**. Каждая очередь (если я правильно понимаю) это **value**. Содержимое (значение) меняется, а структура мапа НЕТ. Очередь же синхронизирована. 

Тут все ОК.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь, во многом разобрался, как-то подзабыл что set не структурная операция, и малехо подзапутался.

Я полностью обновил вопрос, теперь суть задачи станет яснее